# Executing script in ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I load some HTML code into a div with the `$.ajax` function. but the script that I have in `<body>` doesn't execute, can you help me please, it's very important for me.

[image]

This is my HTML main page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Navigation AJAX avec jQuery</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 var $contenu_div = $('#content div');
 
 
 $('#nav li a').on('click', function() {
  var url = $(this).attr('href'); 

   $.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
     $contenu_div.hide().html(html).fadeIn();
    }
   });
    
  return false;
 });
});
</script>
  
</head>
<body>

 <h2>Navigation AJAX with jQuery</h2>

 <div id="menu">
  <ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="pages/page1.html">page 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="pages/page2.html">page 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="pages/page3.html">page 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="pages/page4.html">page 4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div id="content">
  <div>the content of the first page</div>
 </div>
  
  <script src="problem.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have simplified the code

The ajax navigation work perfectly but the `<script src="problem.js"></script>` doesn't execute, what is the problem?

Comment: where is your sample code??

Comment: So what is the probleme

Comment: your codes look fine, it maybe your ajax request not get "success" status. do you check your ajax response status???

Comment: yes, the ajax request work perfectly, but the script doen't execute, it execute only when I refresh the page ( so without ajax ), and sorry for my bad english

Comment: ok you say, you get status 200 on ajax request,and do you check your console when ajax done?is it show any error?? maybe `Cross-Origin Request Blocked` is the problem that your code not execute

Comment: No No , be sure, there is no errors, I read that it's impossible to execute script when call ajax, it is true ??

Comment: ????? some important question. 1) do your main page build with ajax call? 2) you put some script on the "page1.html" and want to be execute??? 3) do you want to build a "Single Page Application"??

Comment: the script "problem.js" work with elements of page1.html, I put the script in page1.html and it doesn't also work. Yes , i want to build "Single Page Application", my application work completely with ajax

Answer (score 1):

You can directly put this ajax function into document.ready function
Like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = $(this).attr('href'), $contenu_div = $('#content div');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $contenu_div.html(html);
            }
        });
  });
```

It will hit the server after loading complete DOM and will pull data from server.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

I've commented to show you what's going on...

```
var $contenu_div = $('#content div');
$('#nav li a').on('click', function() { /* click captured */
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); /* set the URL we want to load */
    $contenu_div.hide().load(url, function(){ /* hide element first, then load it */
      $(this).fadeIn() /* this is the callback which will fadeIn() when content loaded */
    });
    return false; /* stop the click */
});
```

Comment: the script doesn't execute

Comment: What do you mean doesn't execute? Do you see any errors? - you mean problem.js doesn't work?

Comment: No there is no errors, but i doesn't get any result that mean that the script don't work, soory for my english

Comment: What does your network tab show? Does it show the page loading? Is there a response?

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a sample for you, for create full ajax page and work fine for me, but i suggest you to use one of the spa framework like angular,ember. these framework are so usefull

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Navigation AJAX with jQuery</h2>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="page.html">page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="page.html">page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="page.html">page 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="page.html">page 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <button id="click-me">First Click on page 1, then click me</button>
    <div id="content">
        <div>the content of the first page</div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $contenu_div = $('#content div');
    $('#nav li a').on('click', function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $contenu_div.hide().html(html).fadeIn();
            }
        });                
        return false;
    });
    $("#content").on("click", "#click",function(){
        alert("button click");
    })
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

page.html

```
<h2>page 2</h2>
<button id="click">Click me</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // console.log("page 2 is loaded");
        // your code should be here
        $("#click-me").on("click",function(){
            alert("button clicked on main page");
        })
    });
</script>
```